# Grep anything in between two words as long as it's less than specified number of characters?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I'm trying to use something like the pattern "John.*Smith" but instead of matching anything in between *John* and *Smith* I'd like to match anything between the words as long as it's of X characters length or less.

If X = 5 for instance:

Lines that should be a match:

```
- John Smith
- Jonh F. Smith
```

Lines that shouldn't be a match:

```
- John Ferdinand Smith
- Joe Brown; John Johson; Mary Smith
```

How could I do that with grep?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using a "bound".

> man regex:
>
> A bound is '{' followed by an unsigned decimal integer, possibly
> followed by ',' possibly followed by another unsigned decimal integer, always followed  by  '}'.  The integers must lie between 0 and RE_DUP_MAX (255(!)) inclusive, ...

```
grep -E "John.{0,5}Smith" file
John Smith
John F. Smith
```

The `0` can be omitted (EDIT: in some implementations):

```
grep -E "John.{,5}Smith" file
```

Comment: {0,5} works!, Omitting the 0, though, fails with "regex parse error". Adding the backslashes like @Frédéric's answer does not give an error but also does not match the desired lines.

Comment: Note that that would also match `Johnnie Smith`. Or `Mark John; Smith L.J.`. Something like `John [^;]{0,3} Smith` might work to avoid that.

Answer (score 4):

I would use the following command :

`grep 'John.\{,5\}Smith'`

`.` is for any characters.

`\{,5\}` is for the repetition up to 5 times.

Comment: .{0,5} is what worked for me. With  the backslashes the pattern matches no lines

Comment: I had to insert backslashes to make it works… but I didn’t tried `grep -E` or `egrep`.

Comment: The `,n` is for up to 5, which is was in the question.

Comment: @Thums, in "basic regexes" or BRE, as used by `grep`, it's `\{n,m\}` with backslashes. In "extended regexes" or ERE, as used by `grep -E` (and awk and closer to what the more modern ones like Perl regexes look like), it's `{n,m}` without backslashes.

Comment: Omitting the lower bound (i.e. `{,5}` and not `{0,5}`) seems to work in GNU grep and GNU awk, but not in whatever the grep on my Mac is (gives an error), nor in Perl (warns, and matches the characters literally). So yeah, just spell out the `0`.